# Azure integration account creation/update using ARM Templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am using the below templates to create and update the integration account:

1. We are able to create the new integration account using the ARM template
2. We are able to add the Partners to the integration account using the same template.
3. But when we try to add additional Identifiers to the existing partner the template replaces the existing Identifiers in the integration account.

Integration account template:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "integrationaccountname": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "maxLength": 80,
            "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of the Integration Account."
            }
        },
        "integrationaccountpartnername": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "maxLength": 80,
            "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of the Integration Account Partner Name."
            }
        },
        "partnerqualifier": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "maxLength": 4,
            "metadata": {
            "description": "Provide the Partner Qualifier."
            }
        },
        "partnerqualifiervalue": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "maxLength": 80,
            "metadata": {
            "description": "Provide the Partner Qualifier Value."
            }
        },
        "integrationaccountlocation": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "allowedValues": [
                "[resourceGroup().location]",
                "eastasia",
                "southeastasia",
                "centralus",
                "eastus",
                "eastus2",
                "westus",
                "northcentralus",
                "southcentralus",
                "northeurope",
                "westeurope",
                "japanwest",
                "japaneast",
                "brazilsouth",
                "australiaeast",
                "australiasoutheast",
                "southindia",
                "centralindia",
                "westindia",
                "canadacentral",
                "canadaeast",
                "uksouth",
                "ukwest",
                "westcentralus",
                "westus2",
                "koreacentral",
                "koreasouth",
                "francecentral",
                "francesouth"
            ],
            "metadata": {
            "description": "Location of the Integration Account."
            }
        },
        "sku": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Free",
            "allowedValues": [
                "Free",
                "Basic",
                "Standard"
            ],
            "metadata": {
            "description": "Specify the Pricing Tier of the Integration Account."
            }
        },
        "integrationAccountApiVersion": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "2016-06-01"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "[parameters('integrationAccountApiVersion')]",
            "name": "[parameters('integrationaccountname')]",
            "location": "[parameters('integrationaccountlocation')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Logic/IntegrationAccounts",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
            },
            "properties": { 
                    "state": "Enabled"  
                }   
            },  
            {   
                "type": "Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/partners", 
                "apiVersion": "2016-06-01", 
                "name": "[concat(parameters('integrationaccountname'), '/',parameters('integrationaccountpartnername'))]",
                "dependsOn": [  
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts', parameters('integrationaccountname'))]"
                ],  
                "properties": { 
                    "partnerType": "B2B",   
                    "content": {    
                        "b2b": {    
                            "businessIdentities": [ 
                                {   
                                    "qualifier": "[parameters('partnerqualifier')]",    
                                    "value": "[parameters('partnerqualifiervalue')]"    
                                }   
                            ],  
                            "partnerClassification": "NotSpecified" 
                        }   
                    }   
                }
        }
    ]
}
```

Parameters template:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "integrationaccountname": {
            "value": "viswa-int"
        },
        "integrationaccountpartnername": {
            "value": "treasury"
        },
        "partnerqualifier": {
            "value": "ZZZ"
        },
        "partnerqualifiervalue": {
            "value": "Test007"
        },
        "integrationaccountlocation": {
            "value": "eastus"
        },
        "sku": {
            "value": "Free"
        },
        "integrationAccountApiVersion": {
            "value": "2016-06-01"
        }
    }
}
```